# What is the meaning of "Rav"?

Tags: words, hebrew

I see that some names have the word "Rav" in the name, names like Rav Yitzchak Meir Morgenstern and Rav Berg.

I don't know much about Judaism. I want to know what is the meaning of "Rav".

Comment: Welcoem to Mi Yodeya! For general information about the site see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help). Hope to see you around the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sort of context, it is a title roughly analogous to the term "Rabbi." Here is how [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rabbi) defines "Rabbi":

> **rabbi** (plural *rabbis*)
>
> 1. A Jewish scholar or teacher of halacha (Jewish law), capable of making halachic decisions.
> 2. A Jew who is or is qualified to be the leader of a Jewish congregation.

You can find this word in many other dictionaries as well. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi) is Wikipedia's article of that title.

([Here](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/rab%C3%AD) and [here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabino) are the Spanish versions of the above on Wiktionary and Wikipedia respectively.)

Comment: thanks for the info, I see that you put a link in spanish, very friendly on your part

Comment: I see you are a Professor in Cuba, so I figured Spanish was the way to go :)

Comment: In several places in the Mishnah (Oral Law), the term "rav" is used to mean "teacher". As stated in #1, often one of the duties of a rabbi is to teach - either in a yeshiva (school) or he gives lectures in his congregation and / or beyond. He also teaches and advises individual congregants.